# Python Print Variables with parameters

Tags: python, output

I know you can do this for a string:

```
print("You have inputted {0} postive numbers and {1} negative numbers".format('3','2'))
```

And this would produce:

```
You have inputted 3 postive numbers and 2 negative numbers
```

But I want to insert a letter in a variable name. For example,

```
number = 4
print(nu{}ber.format("m"))
```

And this should produce `4` Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(eval('nu{}ber'.format("m")))
```

Eval evaluates the expression from string, and has access to program variables by default.

Or:

```
print(globals()['nu{}ber'.format("m")])
```

Globals is the dictionary {'variable_name': value}.

---

Unless you do trust the source of the string though, you should be careful. Fore example, if you have

```
class Nuke:
    def destroy_everything():
        launch_nukes()

class Cucumber:
    ...

print(eval('nu{}ber'.format(string_received_from_user)))
```

And

```
string_received_from_user = "ke.destroy_everything() or Cucum"
```

Than the command

```
Nuke.destroy_everything() or Cucumber
```

will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not recommended, you can access your variable dynamically through `globals`:

```
>>> number = 4
>>> globals()['num' + 'ber']
4
```

`eval` works too:

```
>>> eval('num' + 'ber')
4
```